# How do you create a center container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how create a center container in html or bootstrap that runs constant down the page maybe like facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the element the entire height of the window, you have to set its height, and all of its ancestor's heights, to 100% (including `html` and `body`).

To center the element horizontally, apply `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
html, body, .main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgb(200,225,250);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Hello foo bar world!</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can utilize `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`

```css
html, body, .main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.main {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px;
  background: rgb(200,225,250);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Hello foo bar world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's [.container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) class does just that. Read the docs!